# Expected right parenthesis in expression at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The Fortran compiler reports an error

```
Expected right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

What does it mean?

```
program energy
real::Es=0.4,Ep=-0.4,ts=0.2,tsp=2.0
integer::Nx=100
real::kx(101)
real::ky

kx(1)=-0.50
do i=1,Nx
  kx(i+1)=kx(1)+i*(1.00/Nx)
end do

print*, 'Enter value for ky'
read*,ky

do i=1,101
  ! "The error mentions it in the next line in terminal"
  Epos(i)=sqrt(-Es*(Ep+2*ts*(cos(kx(i))+cos(ky)))-(2*ts*(cos(kx(i))+cos(ky))*(Ep-2*ts*(cos(kx(i))+cos(ky))))+(4*tsp**2)*((sin(kx(i)))**2 +(sin(ky))**2)))
end do

write(*,*) Epos
end program energy
```

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. Use the tags `fortran90` and `fortran95` when asking a version specific question. Typically, you don't want more of them.

Comment: Sure, I will put more notice next time onwards. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line is too long... You can either specify `-ffree-line-length-0` for `gfortran` to remove the limit, or (what I would prefer), break your lines using `&`:

```
  Epos(i)=sqrt( - Es*(Ep+2*ts*(cos(kx(i))+cos(ky))) &
                - (2*ts*(cos(kx(i))+cos(ky))*(Ep-2*ts*(cos(kx(i))+cos(ky)))) &
                + (4*tsp**2)*((sin(kx(i)))**2 +(sin(ky))**2) )
```

There are two additional issues with your code:

- One right bracket too much
- Missing declaration of `Epos`